# Saving Spark Streaming state into external DB

Tags: save, state, spark-streaming, rdd, flush

Spark Streaming checkpoint won't work if there are any changes to the spark application code... So i want to explicitly save the state info into an external DB like cassandra.

How to FLUSH the spark streaming state to external DB or disk periodically? I don't know how to read all the state RDD info and write to DB/disk. Can someone give me java example?

Comment: Can someone guide me how to FLUSH the spark streaming state data (NOT OUTPUT DATA) to external DB or disk periodically, lets say every 12 hrs?

Answer (score 0):

You might find Spark's [DataSources](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-sources) API documentation useful for saving state; it contains Java examples.

Also there are many stores that can be used in conjunction with Spark. Here are most of them:

- [SnappyData](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata)
- [Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)
- [MemSQL](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector)
- [HBase](https://github.com/hortonworks/shc) (one of many)
- [MongoDB](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark)
- [Redis](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis)
- [Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html)
- [Couchbase](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-spark-connector)

Comment: The documented you have pointed is to save Spark streaming OUTPUT data into external datasources NOT the SPARK STREAMING STATE data. How to FLUSH the spark streaming state to external DB or disk periodically, lets say every 12 hours?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the difference is between outputting data and flushing data that you're alluding to. If you look at [cassandra's docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md) for example, they use .saveToCassandra in both the batch and streaming cases and I'm pretty sure this function just uses the datasources API underneath.

Comment: Plambre, Thanks for the reply... As you might be aware, SPARK has ability to perform stateful event processing. Here is the simplified UseCase. I have stream of events which has customerID, his current location (lat, long coordinates). I want spark to process each event and check if customer current location is one of his previous visited location or not. If not, output an Alert (CustomerID, LOCATION_ANAMOLY).

Comment: Also update Spark STATE which is key, value store of CustomerID, List of his previous visited location, with current location in the event. This state will be in spark memory and will be updated continuously. I want this STATE info. in spark memory to be PERIODICALLY persisted in the external DB. Don't confuse SPARK STATE  with SPARK Processed output (which is LOCATION_ANOMALY alert).

Comment: I can't say I've gotten into the internals of mapWithState, but my naive approach would be flushing data on a timer, or checking for a certain volume and flushing (using the same datasource apis). I don't know that this guarantees fault tolerance in the same way checkpointing does, or storing every piece of data back to a datastore immediately would. Depending on how big your stream is, you may even be able to lookup the customerID in one of the spark + datastore options above, check for an anomaly, update that ID with the new data received and continue.

Comment: @vanba06 I'm running similar application. Let me explain you how it works! I'm maintaining HBase db for storing customer details like customer_id and his previous locations. Then later in spark streaming I'm reading every event and comparing this event with HBase records with that particular customer. If I found take no action else send alert and storing that new location in HBase. The process goes on like this. Is this same are you trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an asynchronous(with minimal effect on Spark execution) call to the DB to store the updated state with the key from groupState Function itself. The other way is to read the checkpoint directory at scheduled intervals and ability to read that something I am exploring.